# Bash command to write the contents of multiple files into a single file

Tags: bash, firebug

I'm wondering what's the best way to combine multiple .html files (spread across many folders) into one single html file. If someone could create a simple bash command that would be fantastic. (This is a workaround so I can use firebug's command line API to effectively search an entire site for html selector combinations. As far as I know, firebug can only search on one page.)

Any help is greatly appreciated for this stymied front-end designer.

Answer (score 7):

```
cat file1.html file2.html file3.html > newfile.html
```

---

Edit
This may be easier

```
find . -name="*.html" | xargs cat >> ../newfile.html
```

Note that newfile.html is pushed up from the current directory so it is not cat'ed into itself.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you're not concerned about the resulting file being correct, `cat` seems like the easiest way to go:

```
cat file1.html file2.html file3.html > result.html
```

But of course each of those files with have an `<html>` tag at the top and a closing one at the bottom, so it won't be a valid HTML file.  Firefox will probably load it, but I don't know how it will display it... perhaps only the first one?

Comment: This does not easily get all the files in the sub-directories.

Answer (score 2):

```
for file in `ls *.html`; do cat "$file" >> output.html; done
```

Comment: Watch out for spaces in file names! I would read the files into an array first, and then iterate over them in a for loop, or maybe use 'while read line; do'

Comment: True, but you go to hell for using spaces in file names. ;)

Answer (score 2):

You cold always use grep to search something in a group of files instead of merging all of the files and then searching that one file.

```
grep <string you are looking for> <folder containing all of files> -r
```

Comment: I think the -r has to come before the string and the folder.

Comment: grep -r <string> <folder> for example "grep -r milquetoast ."

Comment: I thought so at first as well, but it also works at the end; I just did a quick check.