# BASH: Merging multiple files given different file name prefixes in an array

Tags: bash

After looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/640363/bash-command-to-write-the-contents-of-multiple-files-into-a-single-file), it looks like I can just use cat to merge files.

However, I am a bit confused on how to do this with my array of filename prefixes.
For example:

```
prefixes=( pre1 pre2 pre3 pre4 pre5 )
```

If I have an array of prefixes like that, how can I make a command to look like this or do something similar to this:

```
cat pre1.file pre2.file pre3.file pre4.file pre5.file > merged.file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a loop to iterate over the file names in the array:

```
prefixes=( pre1 pre2 pre3 pre4 pre5 )
for p in "${prefixes[@]}"; do cat "$p.file"; done > merged.file
```

Answer (score 0):

If all your prefixes follow a pattern then you can do it using globbing:

```
cat pre*.file > merged.file
```

or

```
cat pre?.file > merged.file
```

Also, you can use brace expansion for a list of prefixes:

```
cat {pre1,pre2,pre3,pre4,pre5}.file > merged.file
```

Answer (score -1):

```
eval "cat {${prefixes[*]}}.file > merged.file"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. The outer braces are keep messing up with the file name and gets included with the name, such as {pre}.file. I tried taking them out, but it still didn't work.